# React <select>'s <option> is not working at onClick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I need a function at every  here is it.
i want to access option value.

```
 const region = ['Africa','America','Asia','Europe','Oceania'];
    <div className="options">
                <select>
                <option>Select a Region</option>
              {region.map((nameOfRegion) => {
               return <option onClick={() => requestRegion(nameOfRegion)}>
               {nameOfRegion}
               </option>
              })}
            </select>
```

this function is not logging options

```
const requestRegion = (region) => {
    console.log(region)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because neither the `onSelect()` nor `onClick()` events are supported by the `option` tag. So you can use `onChange` in `select` tag in this case:

```
const onChange =(e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}

<select name="select" onChange = {onChange}>
      <option>Select a Region</option>
      {region.map((nameOfRegion, i) => {
        return (
          <option key={i}>
            {nameOfRegion}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
```

Note: you need add key in child tag when using `map`

Answer (score 4):

Use `onChange` event on the `<select>`:

```
  const requestRegion = (event) => {
     console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
      <div className="options">
        <select onChange={requestRegion}>
          <option>Select a Region</option>
           {
             region.map((nameOfRegion) => (<option>{nameOfRegion}</option>))
           }
        </select>
     </div>
```

[image: Edit stoic-cohen-d7cyj]

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `onChange` handler on the `select` element, and get the value from the change event:

```js
const Demo = ({ regions }) => {
  const requestRegion = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <select onChange={requestRegion}>
      <option>Select a Region</option>
      {regions.map(region => (
        <option key={region}>{region}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}

const regions = ['Africa','America','Asia','Europe','Oceania']

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo regions={regions} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```